# Events are not getting recognised TypeError: Contract.events.event is not a function

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, events

I am trying to get older state of a contract.
I have deployed contract using truffle.
my contract is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract NDA {
bytes32  party1name;
bytes32  party2name; 
bytes32  pary1regaddr;

event Setparty2 (address indexed _from,bytes32 _party2name);
function NDA() {
    party1name = "Me";
}

function setparty2(bytes32 _party2name, bytes32 _pary1regaddr){
    party2name = _party2name;
    pary1regaddr = _pary1regaddr;
    Setparty2(msg.sender, _party2name);
}

function get() constant returns (bytes32, bytes32) {
    return (party1name, party2name);
}
}
```

When I do `NDA.events`
i get

```
truffle(development)> NDA.events
{ 
'0x851b88ce358750e8e352d86d0712c570afe3624e605413a620f25f7e1c012463':
{ anonymous: false,
 inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
 name: 'Setparty2',
 type: 'event' } }
```

Now I did some transactions with this contract like

```
NDA.at(NDA.address).setparty2("Manish", "Kumar Singh");
```

and then some more .

Now I want to get the previous state of contract, I am trying to use events for that but when i do

```
truffle(development)> NDA.events.Setparty2({fromBlock : 0 });
TypeError: NDA.events.Setparty2 is not a function
```

I am not able to make out how to use my events.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your setparty2 call, try

```
NDA.at(NDA.address).Setparty2({fromBlock: 0});
```